# Using Array in perl to taking user input and calculate the results

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a moderately complex calculation to be made based on the user input and a value.txt file to be calculated using a perl script.  User has a choice of giving an input from the alphabets G C A U. Input can be of any length but a combination of the 4 alphabets mentioned. Based on input, I will need to pair each alphabet them with adjacent one until the last one and print them. An then each pair has a pre-determined value, which needs to be added and print the final output. For example:

```
> input by user after script prompt : ACCGUA
> 
> Script need to pair : AC CC CG GU UA
> 
> read the value of each pair from a values file below:
> 
> value.txt
> 
> AC = 2 CC = 1 CG = AC  GU = UG UG = 4 UA = 0
> 
> Output should be  
> 
>  total value is  9 (2+1+2+4+0)
```

I tried something in shell by defining an array, but getting nowhere in perl.

Comment: What is the format of the file `value.txt`? Are the pairs separated by space, tab, or newline? Are all pairs on a single line?

Comment: tab separated for value and new line for each pair of alphabet

Comment: ok, and on each line you have e.g. `AC 2` and not `AC = 2` ?

Comment: That's Correct.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you want. You might want to add a bit more error checking.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use List::Util 'sum';

my %value_map = load_value_map();

my $input = shift // '';
$input =~ s/[^ACGU]//g;

until ($input) {
  print 'Give me a string of letters [ACGU]: ';
  chomp ($input = <STDIN>);
  $input =~ s/[^ACGU]//g;
}

my @values;

for (0 .. length($input) - 2) {
  my $str = substr $input, $_, 2;
  if (exists $value_map{$str}) {
    push @values, $value_map{$str};
  } else {
    warn "$str is not a valid map key\n";
    next;
  }
}

say 'total value is ', sum(@values), ' (', join('+', @values), ')';

sub load_value_map {
  open my $fh, '<', 'value.txt' or die $!;

  my %value_map = map { chomp; split } <$fh>;

  for (keys %value_map) {
    if ($value_map{$_} =~ /\D+/) {
      $value_map{$_} = $value_map{$value_map{$_}};
    }
  }

  return %value_map;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it is throwing an error at this line 11 which is  `$input =~ s/[^ACGU]//g;` . The error is "Use of Uninitialized value $input in substitution (s///) at test.pl line 11.

Comment: It's a warning, not an error - so it wouldn't stop the code from going on to work. See the fix that I've just made.

Comment: couple things here. That adjustment got rid of the warning but there is another at line 31, `Use of Uninitialized value at in subroutine entry at line 31 and Use of uninitialized value $values[2] in join string at line 31`. And the sum is incorect. It is adding only 2 values. For example I gave the input ACCGC, it only added for the pair AC+CC, but left remaining pairs (CG, GC)

Comment: @MO12: I get 5. Another 1 from CG, but GC is not in the input file so it gives a warning ("GC is not a valid map key") and is ignored. I don't see the "Uninitialized value" errors at all. Can I suggest that you try debugging the problem a bit. Add some `print()` statements. Perhaps use `Data::Dumper`.

Comment: Thank you. I am working on debugging. Yes, GC is not in the value.txt file I provided, but is in the original file I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example (using object oriented Perl):

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

Compute->new( fn => 'value.txt' );

package Compute;
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my ( $class, %args ) = @_;
    my $self = bless \%args, $class;

    $self->read_map();
    $self->cleanup_map();
    $self->input_text();
    $self->gen_pairs();
    $self->compute_sum();
}

sub compute_sum {
    my ( $self ) = @_;

    my $map = $self->{map};
    my $sum = 0;
    for my $pair ( @{ $self->{pairs} } ) {
        if ( exists $map->{$pair} ) {
            $sum += $map->{$pair};
        }
        else {
            die "Undefined pair: '$pair'\n";
        }
    }
    say "Sum = ", $sum;
}

sub gen_pairs {
    my ( $self ) = @_;

    my $txt = $self->{txt};
    my @chars = split //, $txt;
    my @pairs;
    for my $i (0..($#chars - 1)) {
        push @pairs, $chars[$i] . $chars[$i+1];
    }
    $self->{pairs} = \@pairs;
}

sub input_text {
    my ( $self ) = @_;

    print "Enter text: ";
    my $txt = <STDIN>;
    if ( defined $txt ) {
        $txt =~ s/^\s+//;
        $txt =~ s/\s+$//;
        if ( (length $txt) >= 2 ) {
            $self->{txt} = $txt;
            return;
        }
    }
    say "No input.";
    exit;
}

sub cleanup_map {
    my ( $self ) = @_;

    my $map = $self->{map};
    while (1) {
        my $modified = 0;
        for my $key ( keys %$map ) {
            my $value = $map->{$key};
            if ( $value =~ /^[A-Za-z]+$/ ) {
                if ( exists $map->{$value} ) {
                    $map->{$key} = $map->{$value};
                    $modified = 1;
                }
                else {
                     die "Undefined value: '$value'\n";
                }
            }
        }
        last if !$modified; 
    }
}

sub read_map {
    my ( $self ) = @_;

    my $fn = $self->{fn};
    my %map;
    open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        chomp $line;
        my ( $key, $value ) = split " ", $line;
        if ( (defined $key) && (defined $value) ) {
            if ( length $key != 2 ) {
                die "Bad input key\n";
            }
            $map{$key} = $value;
        }
    }
    close $fh;
    $self->{map} = \%map;
}
```

Comment: thank you. I will try this. I thought this is much simpler program,  I am incorrect.

Comment: I realized you mention using OOP perl, will it be different if you are not using OOP concepts.